# Как получить файл на сервер, не зная его имени?

Tags: php

Друзья, ситуация такая. Есть некий скрипт, который хочет загрузить файл на сервер по команде вида. Как описано в документации (которая очень убогая), метод загрузки POST, это и понятно. К сожалению я не понимаю как его можно получить на своей стороне, так как я не вижу ни в документации, а заглянуть в средину я также не могу, как называется имя файла который будут загружать. Можно ли как то это обойти и грузить все файлы которые будут поступать по такой команде?

```
http://domain.com/index.php?r=Terminals/Upload&id=1111
```

Обработка тех файлов у которых ЕСТЬ имя я делаю так (загрузка аватара к примеру):

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"]))
{
  $filename = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];

  mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000); $img = "";
  for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $img .= chr(rand(97, 122));
  }

  $newfilename = 'agent-'.$img;
  $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/users/".$newfilename.$ext);
}
```

Comment: не очень понятен вопрос. в обработчике загрузки сделайте print_r($_FILES) и посмотрите результат.

Comment: Вопрос вот в чем, скрипт через свою форму отправляет файл. Я не знаю что у него написано в name в его форме. Поэтому $_FILES["имя файла незнаю какое писать"]

Comment: Возможно вы просто поможе мне таким способом, мне надо знать $_FILES["вот это имя"]["tmp_name"] любого из файлов который придет на сервер

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не видя кода, который отправляет, сложно что-то посоветовать. Если имя инпута для файла (в примере это "avatar") каждый раз произвольное, то можно использовать

```
foreach($_FILES as $k=>$v){
    // тут что-то полезное
}
```

или

```
$inputNames = array_keys(($_FILES);
```

или (для одного файла)

```
reset($_FILES);
$inputName = key($_FILES);
```

Comment: Отлично! Да вы правы. Я действительно не могу посмотреть код который отправляет скрипт. Поэтому к таким методам и нужно прибегать. Спасибо большое третий вариант как раз подходит.это как раз то что мне нужно

Comment: Так, в копилку, как замена последнему `current($_FILES)`.

Comment: если вы где-то раньше по коду уже итерировались по $_FILES, то current($_FILES) вернёт false. Если достаточно всегда брать первый элемент, то лучше reset($_FILES) - он не только перематывает внутренний указатель на начало, но и возвращает первый элемент (если массив не пуст)